# How to add `0` this kind of condition in code?

Tags: javascript

I have this code below working fine but I am trying to do is if I input a `5:30` the code will auto add the `0` so the output would be `05:30`.

I try to edit the code like the `JSFIDDLE 2` but I failed to do it.

Is it possible what I want the output to be?.

**HTML :**

```
    <div>
    <input id="Departure" type="text" style="width: 50px; text-align: center" placeholder="00:00" maxlength = "5" />
    </div>
```

**JavaScript :**

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('Departure').addEventListener('keyup',
        function(event) {
            if(event.target.value.length === 2) {
            if((event.key && !isNaN(event.key)) || (event.keyCode >= 48 && event.keyCode <= 57)) {
          if(!isNaN(event.target.value) && parseInt(event.target.value) > 12) {
          event.target.value = event.target.value.slice(0,1) + ':' + event.target.value.substring(1);
          } else {
                event.target.value += ':';
          }
        }
      }
    });
</script>
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/87x28zud/5/)

[JSFIDDLE 2](https://jsfiddle.net/87x28zud/6/)

Comment: Why cant you use a datepicker?

Comment: @ShankarShastri sorry i can't modify my view that easily because i am following a standard view.

Comment: You have more problems with your code. You auto-insert a `:` after the first char, so you can't input `15:30`, it becomes `1:530`

Comment: @Chewtoy thats why if it is possible or not.

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this:

```
'0' + event.target.value.slice(0,1).slice(-2)
+ ':' +
'0' + event.target.value.substring(1).slice(-2)
```

ie., you can pad a zero at the beginning of your value and then slice two digits from the last.

Comment: Please explain your answer.

Comment: @Uki:- I am not sure then if I understood it correctly, what I thought is you can pad a zero to your input value and then slice 2 digits from the last. It would give you the result with padded zero(*if required*)

Comment: sorry if you don't understand it well. if i input a single hour it would auto add `0`. for example `5:30` so it would be `05:30`

Comment: @RahulTripathi can you provide a jsfiddle?